# How to embed a local iframe into a Wordpress page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I developed a module which has separate styling from my wordpress site. I want to integrate it into the site through an iframe, however I researched that Wordpress strips iframes. I've checked out numerous plugins that give iframe shortcode support, however they all assume that the iframe is external (whereas my is hosted within the site).

I'm open to both plugins, changing the actual code, or any advanced solution.

Comment: Shouldn't all iframes, regardless of internal or external, have URLs?

Comment: How do Wordpress URLs work? I tried using a URL rewrite, but it didn't seem to allow anything that wasn't index.php.

Comment: Well, how do you view your separated module from your browser?what's that URL?

Comment: @tuananh I developed it locally (localhost). I uploaded it to Wordpress in the directory of the theme.

Comment: There you go! the URL should be in the format of `http://yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/your_theme_name/your_module.html`

Comment: @tuananh strange, the entire directory is accessible to the public?

Comment: @tuananh yeah I just tested it, that's really strange. It's been a long time since I worked with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**iFrame Plugin**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/iframe/).

Sample Usage.

```
[iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/4qsGTXLnmKs" width="100%" height="500"]
```

Comment: the website I'm trying to embed is local on my server. How would I get the URL for it?

Comment: put it on a live server? (purchase one)

Comment: I thought of that, but isn't that a lot slower?

Comment: Per the comments to the question: the theme directory is accessible to the public, so you can put a php file there.